# Recovery Routines after Training Sessions

Tags: training

Hey is anyone following any flexibility/recovery routines? Started to up my cycling but have had previous knee and hip problems and want to stay on top of it. Someone has suggested a [vibrating foam roller](https://www.google.com/search?q=vibrating+foam+roller&oq=vibrating+foam+roller&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l6j69i61.3371j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), does anyone have experience or advice?

Comment: I would suggest splitting this into two questions, one for general recovery, streches and cool downs and one for knee issues. Here's a good youtube vid I used for knee issues in the past, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hA4NY6N5_hg It's only an introduction to knee issues and strengthening but you can use it for further research

Comment: @abdnChap great video link by the way.  I think Naudi Aguilar has a great system, and I have personally had great results using the functional patterns approach. As a funny aside, they would generally be against cycling as a primary form of exercise due to the activity being primarily in the sagittal plane.

Comment: Wait... are you saying that sitting in an armchair and drinking a beer isn't a good routine?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Your question has been flagged as spam. I have replaced the questionable link with a general Google search. If you would like to further improve that link, please do so. Also, if you revert the link and are affiliated with the product, [you must disclose your affiliation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) within the body of your post.

Comment: @jimchristie Looks like they reverted the link

Comment: If this is spam, its doing well at attracting negatives without showing positives.

Comment: @Das_Geek thanks - re-reverted.

Comment: @kit are you link-spamming ?   Do you have an association or affiliation with this product?  Or is it a legitimate question about this kind of item?

Answer (score 4):

A vibrating foam roller sounds like a gimmick.  The key to myofascial releases with a foam roller or ball is being able to relax the muscle when rolling.  You want to aim for an intense sensation, not pain. The moment you perceive a sensation as pain you will instinctively try and protect the muscle by contracting it.  Foam Rolling a contracted muscle will have no positive effect, and at worse may bruise the tissue.

This [balance between pain and sensation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XG1A-Ct69ug&t=462s) can take a while to develop. Remember to also take measured breaths that are deep and slow as this type of breathing will actually help to to relax the body (i.e., parasympathetic).

Your body is a [tensegrity object](https://www.anatomytrains.com/fascia/tensegrity/), where excess muscle tension in one part can impact functioning and tension elsewhere. I have personally found doing an audit of your body and learning where you hold excess tension (e.g., muscle knots), then habitually releasing the muscle tension can do wonders for chronic injuries/pain. Cycling is a non-natural activity, and as such it is easy to develop tension imbalances which can lead to issues latter on.

Finally, as for static stretching, there [doesn’t appear to be scientific support](https://www.outsideonline.com/2408467/case-against-stretching-flexibility-research) that it does much for you.  To clarify, this doesn't mean range of motion is not important, only that at the *static* stretching on its own does not appear to produce any consistent measurable benefit at the population level. This implies that flexibility is a complex subject.  Likely, the lack of a population level benefit has to do with [the way static stretching is used](https://www.functionalpatterns.com/why-do-you-need-to-stretch/). It helps us understand what we need to work on, but only doing *static stretching* without accompanying work  (e.g., muscle releases,  strength, range of motion, and coordination exercises) will likely not produce any benefit. This can be difficult to implement, and most people who "stretch" just do a couple stretches and leave it at that, which is why the  [scientific studies](https://www.outsideonline.com/2408467/case-against-stretching-flexibility-research) are not finding consistent benefits when averaged across individuals (i.e., population level effects).

Personally, I have found great utility in doing releases and range of motion exercises (e.g., balance lunges, squats) for returning flexibility and range of motion in the hips. Hip problems are quite common for cyclists, and one potential cause is muscle imbalances in the hip (e.g., inactive glues) that can impact range of motion and how the hip functions through the range of motion. Compensatory patterns can develop, which over work other muscle groups, which can lead to pain. Again this is a strength and functional training issue, rather than a "stretching" issue per se.

Comment: I have to strongly disagree with the comment against static stretching. Although being flexible might not directly help you be stronger or have more endurance, being flexible does help against many many types of injuries, and in a lot of case, not being flexible enough to do a full range of muscle function means that the muscle won't train at it's full potential. At what point does flexibility stop helping is a different matter, but you can't just say that from one article.

Comment: @abdnChap it’s not that flexibility is not important, is that _static_ stretching has little impact on flexibility. One of the issues is we are often not “stretching” soft tissue, but rather fighting against contracting muscles - i.e., your brain is trying to prevent a joint from entering a particular range of motion; it can be good to understand why, rather than force it. In other circumstances you may actually need to do muscle releases rather than stretch. Our relationship with stretching is complicated, blanket suggestions to just “stretch” could end up hurting more than helping.

Comment: @abdnChap  Also we have to consider how muscles work.  Muscles do not elongate (i.e., stretch) on their own, they do so through the contraction of an antagonist muscle group.  Static stretching does not replicate this basic functioning, active range of motion exercises do.  Static stretching can be useful to understand where your range of motion is at (i.e., an audit), but it won't do a lot for actually increasing range of motion unless you are combining it with other activities (i.e., releases, exercises, etc)

Comment: Updated answer to better discuss some of the nuances around why _static_ stretching _on its own_ is not likely to produce any meaningful benefits.

Comment: Corrected the link to the video about [pain vs sensation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XG1A-Ct69ug) video featuring Thomas Myers, which is really worth watching for those learning the mental aspects surrounding myofascial releases.

Comment: Thanks for the informative response!

Answer (score 0):

I've checked with a guy at work who uses rollers to release muscles after long/hard rides, and Tim confirms that the vibrating rollers are **utterly useless**

The main purpose of a foam roller is to make the muscle fibres untension through pressure, and the vibration ones **do not achieve the same results** as a plain firm foam one.

Related - the vibrations are able to **induce cramps**, and the foam tends to be too squishy - not be hard enough to use normally.

Upshot: **don't bother with vibrating rollers** - use a firm foam roller of around 4-6 inches (10-15 cm) in diameter and 12-18 inches long (30-50 cm)